# Java stream batch process of list

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I've a list and I wanted to take every '25' items from the list and send it to a method that returns a map.

The `batches` method below would give me a list stream of 25 items and its working fine

The code throws a incompatible types when I try to assign it to a map

This is what I wrote

```
public class Processor{
@Inject
private Delivery delivery;

public String process(List<String> item) throws Exception{

Map<String,List<String>> tempMap = batches(item,25).forEach(i -> delivery.process(i));
//the method delivery.process would take a list and returns a map(string,list)
}
public static  Stream<List<String>> batches(List<String> source, int length) {
    if (length <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("length = " + length);
    int size = source.size();
    if (size <= 0)
        return Stream.empty();
    int fullChunks = (size - 1) / length;
    return IntStream.range(0, fullChunks + 1).mapToObj(
            n -> source.subList(n * length, n == fullChunks ? size : (n + 1) * length));
}


}
```

Comment: forEach doesn't return a map.

Comment: Is there a way to call the delivery.process method for each stream

Comment: what is the key of your map?

Comment: @YCF_L Its a map(string,list<string>)

Comment: each call to `delivery.process` returns a new Map according to your comments in the code. Instead of `forEach` you can use `map` and `collect` to save the resulting maps in a list.

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer Could you please explain it in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach` doesn't  return a `Map` it is a `void` return type method, Also even if it return a `Map`, the `tempMap` will be overridden each time, So you have to do something else instead of `forEach`, or do it like this:

```
    Map<String, List<String>> tempMap = new HashMap<>();
    batches(item, 25).forEach(i -> {
        tempMap.putAll(delivery.process(i));
    });
```

Comment: This solution only works if there are no duplicate keys between invocations of `delivery.process`

Comment: Sure, any duplicate key its value will be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by others already, the reason why your code is not working is due to the fact that `forEach` is a *terminal* operation which returns *void*.

as for preventing the problem, I'd go with something as such:

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = 
                        batches(item, 25)
                        .map(delivery::process)
                        .collect(HashMap::new, Map::putAll, Map::putAll);
```

Comment: You could also use the `reduce` operation